# Is it possible to find out the location of a search result from within the Start Menu of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

With Windows 7, I was able to perform a search for a program/file from within the Search box of the Start Menu, right-click the resulting search match and click "Properties" to easily find out the location of what I was about to open. With Windows 10, however, performing a right-click on any search results doesn't appear to display a context menu from where this can be done.

Is there an alternative way of carrying out this task on Windows 10, or is it just not possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover the cursor over the result and it will tell you where its located.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Apologies - I should have mentioned that I'm totally blind and use a screen reader, and unfortunately it doesn't look like this info is presented is a tooltip. Is there any other way?

Comment: Right clicking an item will display a context menu that has an "Open file location" option that will open File Explorer to the location that contains the file.